# Back-substitution in Python for 3x3 matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numerical-methods

```
import numpy as np


A = np.matrix([[1,1,-1],[0,1,3],[0,0,-6]])
b = np.array([9,3,8])


def back_sub(A,b):
    n = len(A)
    print('n is:', n)
    x = [0]*n
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1): #this refers to the rows; i goes 2,1,0
        for j in range(i+1,n): 
            b[i] = b[i] - A[i,j]*x[j]
        x[i] = b[i]/A[i,i]

    return x
```

I am trying to back substitute an upper-triangular matrix A, and come up with an answer: x1=4/3,x2=7,x3=−4/3
.

When I run my code, it gives correct answer for x2
 and x3
, but x1
 comes out as 0, which is confounding. I have tried to debug my code, and it seems to run fine until i=0
. Why isn't this code giving me the correct value of x1
?

Comment: `for j in range(i+1,n):` doesn't even run with `i = 2`, `n = 3`

Comment: Play your program by hand. 3x3 is not a big deal.